# Logback logger logging twice

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I would like to use slf4j+logback for two purposes in my application - log and audit.

For logging, I log the normal way:

```
static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);
logger.debug("-> main()");
```

For Audit, I create a special named logger and log to it:

```
static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("AUDIT_LOGGER");
Object[] params =
    { new Integer(1) /* TenantID */, new Integer(10) /* UserID */, msg};
logger.info("{}|{}|{}", params);
```

logback configuration:

```
<logger name="AUDIT_LOGGER" level="info">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}|%msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</logger>

<root level="all">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</root>
```

Problem:
Messages logged through audit logger appear twice - once under the AUDIT_LOGGER and once under the root logger.

> 14:41:57.975 [main] DEBUG com.gammay.example.Main - -> main()
>
> 14:41:57.978|1|10|welcome to main
>
> 14:41:57.978 [main] INFO AUDIT_LOGGER - 1|10|welcome to main

How can I make sure audit messages appear only once under the audit logger?

Comment: Switch off additivity on audit logger.

Comment: @RaviH Sorry can you please explain? Did you mean remove the appender for audit logger?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change audit logger definition as shown below. Note `additivity="false"` flag in the logger definition.

```
<logger name="AUDIT_LOGGER" level="info" additivity="false">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}|%msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
</logger>
```

That will avoid logging this again in root logger. Read logback configuration documentation for more information.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem, but I think the correct solution is different from what's proposed here through `additivity`. The attached diagram tries to visualize the two approaches that *do not* result in duplicate logs:

1. For every `<logger>` you also add an `<appender>` and disable additivity. This is what's shown in the diagram under "Without additivity". The result is that each individual logger passes the logs directly to the appender and does *not* pass them to the `ROOT` logger.
2. You specify the `<logger>`s and their log levels, but omit `appender-refs` for all but the `ROOT` logger, and leave additivty on. This is shown under "With addivity". The result is that a matching log from the `com.foo` logger is passed to the ROOT logger and uses the `<appender>` specified there. **Note that, at that point, the log level filtering of the `ROOT` logger does not apply anymore**. This means that even though `com.foo` is of log level `INFO` and the `ROOT` logger specifies `ERROR`, the log is still shown because it was already matched by `com.foo`.

[image: Visualization of the data flow from logger to appender in the two scenarios described above]

Comment: "Note that, at that point, the log level filtering of the ROOT logger does not apply anymore" - this tripped me up.  I expected the level of the parent logger to apply to messages also handled by a child logger.  I was therefore quite surprised to see `TRACE` messages in an `INFO`-level log.  I couldn't find anything about this behavior in the logback manual so I appreciate your emphasis on that particular point.  This behavior is counterintuitive to me; I expected a log's level to be applied to everything going into that log.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Add `additivity="false"` to the `"AUDIT_LOGGER"`, as described in one of the answers above, to not inherit the appenders from the `root` logger.
2. Remove the `appender` element from the `"AUDIT_LOGGER"`.  This will cause the `"AUDIT_LOGGER"` to inherit the appenders from the `root` logger.
3. Be careful including other config files, which can also cause duplicate logging. In my case, I had to remove `base.xml` include block, which defines a root logger and appenders.

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml">
```

NOTE: I would suggest defining the appenders outside of your loggers an referring to them by the `appender-ref` element.  This way you can have multiple loggers referring to the same appender.  See logback docs.

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS}|%msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="AUDIT_LOGGER" level="info" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>
```