# spring kafka - set consumer log level manually (spring 5)

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, slf4j, spring-kafka

We are working on `spring` project and integrated with `spring-kafka` recently. It's working as expected where we are able produce and consume messages properly.

But as we moved project to *PROD*, we are getting *DEBUG* level log statements and amount of statements overwhelmed. ***We are trying to set logging levels to WARN or ERROR*** specifically for Kafka logs.

In process we added **`logback.xml`** (added in main/resources) by following below article but no luck, also tried other solutions we came across in internet. (adding *log4j.properties* and *log4j2.xml*)

- https://www.baeldung.com/logback

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration name="default">

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
       <encoder>
          <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache.kafka"                 level="error" />
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka.common.metrics"  level="error"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients"         level="error"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals"          level="error"/>
    <logger name="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher"  level="error"/>
     
    <root level="error" name="org.apache.kafka" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root> 
    
</configuration>
```

**Sample logs:**

```
[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - [Consumer clientId=client-01, groupId=publisher] Cluster ID: Udhjf-fdbfds
[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=client-01, groupId=publisher] Discovered group coordinator 127.....0 (id: 65654654654 rack: null)
[org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator -  [Consumer clientId=client-01, groupId=publisher] (Re-)joining group
[WebSphere non-WLM Dispatch Thread t=008abcf0] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - The configuration 'schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config.
[WebSphere non-WLM Dispatch Thread t=008abcf0] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 2.7.1
[WebSphere non-WLM Dispatch Thread t=008abcf0] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 616tyu85d0d567566
```

Anyone came across similar situation or any leads will be really helpful.  Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Have you tried using Boot's logging config in `application.properties/yml`? `logging.level.org.apache.kafka=warn` ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels

Comment: @GaryRussell we are working with spring (not spring boot), so NO. But tried `log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=warn` in log4j.proerties. could you please suggest any other way with spring..

Comment: Which logging library are you actually using? logback XML only works if you have slf4j-log4j12 bridge and logback dependency. log4j2 configs only work if you have that and also the slf4j-log4j12 bridge. Out of the box, Kafka uses `log4j.properties` (I assume your post as a typo and is missing the `j`). You may also need to modify your websphere logging configs

Comment: @OneCricketeer we are using mentioned dependencies (logback-core, slf4j-api, logback-classic) in article, will add slf4j-log4j12 bridge and update. While testing with log4j.properties we are having dependencies of log4j-core, log4j-api, log4j-slf4j-impl (2.4.1). Please let me know websphere logging config details we need any.

Comment: Those last three would pick up a `log4j2` file, not `log4j`. The file shown in the question is for logback, though

Comment: You can debug logback.xml by adding `debug="true"` to the opening `<configuration>`. With log4j2 it's `status="debug"` https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: @Ganesh If you found any solution please post it as answer. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh Please check posted answer which helped us to resolve the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer, but might be helpful for someone.

We did few changes in same ***logback.xml*** file and also added ***log4j2.xml*** in order to make it work in our application. Below are the changes from both files, please give it a try.

> **logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration name="default">
   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
     <encoder>
        <pattern> %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
  </appender>
  
  <logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml"            level="error"/>
  <logger name="org.apache.http"                 level="error" />
  <logger name="org.apache.http.wire"            level="error"/>
  <logger name="org.apache.commons.httpclient"   level="error"/>
  
  <logger name="org.springframework" level="error">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger> 
  
  <logger name="org.springframework.kafka" level="error" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>

  <logger name="org.apache.kafka" level="info" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </logger>
   
  <root level="error">
      <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root> 

</configuration>
```

> **log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//log4j/log4j Configuration//EN" "log4j.dtd">  
<log4j:configuratio xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">  

   <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">  
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">  
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />  
       </layout>  
   </appender>  

   <appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">  
       <param name="append" value="true" />  
       <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />  
       <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />  
       <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/myStruts1App.log" />  
       <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">  
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />  
       </layout>  
   </appender>  

   <logger name="org.springframework">
      <level value="error" />
   </logger>

   <logger name="org.springframework.kafka">
      <level value="error" />
   </logger>

   <logger name="org.apache.http">
      <level value="warn" />
   </logger>
   
   <logger name="org.apache.http.wire">
      <level value="warn" />
   </logger>

   <logger name="org.apache.commons.httpclient">
      <level value="warn" />
   </logger>

   <logger name="org.apache.kafka">
      <level value="error" />
   </logger>

   <root>  
       <!-- DEBUG level for all other loggers -->
       <priority value="debug" />  
       <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />  
       <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />  
   </root>  

</log4j:configuration>
```

We can observe few changes here related to addivity, try to check below articles to know more about it.

- https://newsbasis.com/what-is-additivity-in-logback/
- [Logback logger logging twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180772/logback-logger-logging-twice)