# Spring sending logs twice to syslog server

Tags: java, spring, logback

I have a spring application with the following logback config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <logger name="PAPERTRAIL_LOGGER" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender name="PAPERTRAIL" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
            <syslogHost>[HOST]</syslogHost>
            <port>[PORT]</port>
            <facility>user</facility>
            <suffixPattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] %clr(%5p) KOCH --- %ex{full}</suffixPattern>
        </appender>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

But when I send a log message with the following code:

```
LoggerFactory.getLogger("PAPERTRAIL_LOGGER").error("Error: ", throwable);
```

Spring is sending two set of messages, one formatted by the suffixPattern provided:

```
Jun 13 10:45:04 DEVLINUSCUA03 DEVLINUSCUA03 [2022-06-13 14:45:04.320] ERROR KOCH --- org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "forcederror" does not exist   Position: 15     at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365) [...]
```

and another broken in lines:

```
Jun 13 10:45:04 DEVLINUSCUA03 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException ERROR: relation "forcederror" does not exist   Position: 15
 Jun 13 10:45:04 DEVLINUSCUA03 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2675)
 Jun 13 10:45:04 DEVLINUSCUA03 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2365)
 Jun 13 10:45:04 DEVLINUSCUA03 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:355)
 Jun 13 10:45:04 DEVLINUSCUA03 at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:490)
[...]
```

How can I make it for spring to not send the second message to the syslog server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180772/logback-logger-logging-twice has some answers that may help.

Comment: @j_b I have followed that question's answers and still get duplicated logs (I even copied the additivity="false" from one answer)

Answer (score 0):

Using your exact configuration (minus a postgres implementation) I get but a single log entry.  I suspect that the postgres logger is doing this for you.  Try disabling it and see what happens, then you can dive in to its configuration

```
<logger name="org.postgresql" level="OFF"/>`
```

Comment: Same thing still happens.

Comment: @MathiasHillmann You can also try disabling it via the logger properties:

logging:
    level:
      org:
        postgresql: OFF

in your application.yml

or logging.level.org.postgresql=OFF in your application.properties

Comment: Still happens, I do think that its spring's general stdout logging that somehow is getting sent to the syslog server, rather than just postgres, as the same thing happens with Oracle, Firebird, Db2 and Mysql.